# Ipdb not showing output with Django nose tests

Tags: django, nose, pdb, ipdb

I'm running the most recent version of ipdb 0.10.0
and when I run the my django test suite using the nosetests plugin, once I hit a `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()` call,  I can't see the prompt.

I've tried adding a '-s' parameter in the nose args, which shows the prompt, but doesn't properly capture they keyboard input in ipdb. e.g I lose input history with up and down arrow keys.

Finally, I've tried using ipdb 0.9.3 again, and it works properly.

I'm wondering if there is any way to fix this issue using the latest release of ipdb? Is there a new configuration mechanism?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As they point in the [docs](https://github.com/gotcha/ipdb#issues-with-stdout), this behaviour has changed, and now you have to use
`ipdb.sset_trace()` instead of `ipdb.set_trace()`.